# Any advantage of jquery .submit() vs jquery .click() if calling .post() in the event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a modal window with address fields in it. I'm trying to understand if I even need a form tag wrapped around my address fields?

When I press the submit/save button, I'm calling .post() to send the address to the controller and if the address is found with Google Maps I update/save the address and send back some data to fill in the map. I also close the modal. If the address isn't found I just show an error message.

Do I really need a ajax.submit here with a form tag wrapped around the fields?
What advantage does it provide me for the situtaion I have?

Comment: The main reason for using the "submit" event on a form is to allow users to submit by hitting `enter`

Comment: validation for the form will also trigger on submit, but not on click

Comment: You can fire validation on a click event.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a form tag, you can't just pass the serialized form object in as a parameter, you have to manually create the data object to pass into your submission object.

You can just do `data: $("#formId").serialize()` in your ajax params

Comment: oh interesting. I was reading each field and putting it into a JSon string then passing the JSon string to the controller. Maybe this isn't the best way??

Comment: That's more or less opinion I think. This way is probably easier to read than JSON

Answer (score 1):

if you have a typical form in your dom as

```
<form id="myform" action="/someUrl" method="post">
    <!-- some fields -->
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And you add a click event to the submit button, both will fire (first the click event and later the submit event).

In that case you would need to do something like the following in order to avoid that the submit event get fired

```
$("#submitButton").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //do necessary stuff.
});
```

Consider that using this approach will work only when the user "click" in the element that handle the form submission and when the key "enter" is pressed the event will not fire.

I prefer to use always a FORM tag, for me at least is more readable and it have a few advantages.

For example,  I think for get all the values you should do something like:

No form tag:

```
$( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize();
```

With form tag:

```
 $("#myForm").serialize();
```